What if user closes his browser before woocommerce_payment_complete action is performed?
I created an action that is performed after the user's payment is complete and it's working fine. But in a situation where my client exits his browser right after payment this action will not be performed. That is a problem because the action creates an API call with a hotel reservation. How can I ensure that the action is executed reliably, even if the user closes their browser immediately after making the payment?
I was thinking about creating a simple server-based app, which sends a call to WooCommerce API to get new orders but I guess there is a simpler way.

Creating a server-based app could work, but it might be an overkill for this problem. Instead, consider using the WooCommerce Webhooks, which are more reliable for your use case. You can set up a webhook to trigger the order.completed event, which will send a POST request to the URL you specify, containing all the order details. This way, even if the user closes their browser, the webhook still gets triggered.

https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/working-with-webhooks-in-woocommerce/

Alternatively, you can use WordPress cron functionality, which is another simpler solution. Here's an example to direct you in the right direction:
add_action('init', 'setup_schedule');
function setup_schedule() {
if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_custom_hook')) {
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_custom_hook');
}
}

add_action('my_custom_hook', 'do_this_hourly');
function do_this_hourly() {
//your logic to check for completed orders and trigger the action
}

I hope this gets you going in the right direction to get the job done.
